# Mouse cursor wonky on Mint 16?

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

Mint 16, having an intermittent problem.

sometimes mouse is normal, sometimes it goes into a period of time where it just doesn't move right. you go left, it goes sort of leftish. Sometimes moving the cursor is like pushing against a wall, you have to keep going left and the cursor jiggles but doesn't go the proper amount of left for the amount of physical movement. It feels like I'm fighting with it. You know what it's like when there are two mouses connected to a computer and someone is screwing with you by moving the other mouse? That. except it doesn't move on  it's own, so I don't think there's another user. It goes away after a while, for a while, till it comes back. during the periods of wonkyness, the mouse is unusable.

Mouse is wired.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Put a CPU monitor on your desktop to check the possibility that sudden spikes in CPU usage aren't causing it.

Comment: Running Gnome System Monitor, no CPUs are over 50% while the problem is occurring. Generally, they're sitting about 10% or less each.